# How to reload the terraform provider at runtime to use the different AWS profile

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How to reload the terraform provider at runtime to use the different AWS profile.

Create a new user

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "user_lake_admin" {

  name = var.lake_admin_user_name
  path = "/"
  tags = {
    tag-key = "data-test"
  }
}
```

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = aws_iam_access_key.user_lake_admin_AK_SK.id
  secret_key = aws_iam_access_key.user_lake_admin_AK_SK.secret
  region                  = "us-west-2"
  alias                   = "lake-admin-profile"
}
```

this lake_admin user is created in the same file.

trying to use

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = aws_iam_access_key.user_lake_admin_AK_SK.id
  secret_key = aws_iam_access_key.user_lake_admin_AK_SK.secret
  region                  = "us-west-2"
  alias                   = "lake-admin-profile"
}
resource "aws_glue_catalog_database" "myDB" {
  name  = "my-db"
  provider = aws.lake-admin-profile
}
```

As I know terraform providers are executed first in all terraform files.

**But is there any way we can reload the configurations of providers in the mid of terraform execution?**

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this rather than have the user that creates the `lake-admin` user also create the Glue catalog?

Comment: Because even though you have admin permission in AWS, we cant add glue DB untill we provide the data lake admin permission. And I cant provide the data lake admin permission to my root provider because that I am using the was an I am role. that will not be the same for all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this directly.

You can apply the creation of the user in one root module and state and use its credentials in a provider for the second.

For the purposes of deploying infrastructure, you are likely better off with IAM Roles and assume role providers to handle this kind of situation.

Generally, you don't need to create infrastructure with a specific user. There's rarely an advantage to doing that. I can't think of a case where the principal creating infrastructure has any implied specific special access to the created infrastructure.

You can use a deployment IAM Role or IAM User to deploy everything in the account and then assign resource based and IAM policy to do the restrictions in the deployment.